# What determines the width of an <ol> with {display:inline-block;}?

Tags: width, html-lists, css

I have an `<ol>` element to which I'd like to apply a background color. I don't want the background color to cover the entire width of the `<ol>`'s parent but rather just its contents + some padding.

Setting `{display:inline-block;}` on the `<ol>` basically does the trick but somehow Google Chrome decides that the `<ol>`'s width should be **462px**. This causes the third `<li>` to break over two physical lines which is neither necessary nor desired.

[image]

Where do the **462px** come from? How can I keep the third `<li>` on a single line? I don't want to set the `<ol>`'s width to a static value since I've many such `<ol>`s. Using `{float:left;}` rather than `{display:inline-block}` triggers similar behavior but also forces me to clear whatever element comes after the `<ol>`. Giving the `<ol>` a `width` of `auto` doesn't seem to change a thing (I suspect it already was `auto`). Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried to give `100%` width?

Comment: @Morpheus: thanks but neither applying `width:100%` to the `<ol>` nor to its `<li>` elements solved the issue.

Comment: how about white-space: nowrap ?

Comment: post your code here.. maybe a simple jsfiddle will help us to start with instead of a image.

Comment: In order to discard a declaration priority issue, test with an inline style applied to the element in your HTML code (set there your width:auto. Remeber this is just for testing) This will give the highest priority to your declaration. if the problem does not arise, then you should check your user  and agent css declarations and defaults where most probable you will find the source of the problem.(check your reset css as well)

Comment: @hcharge: thank you, I never heard of the `white-space` property but it does prevent the `<li>` from breaking. However, the text now extends beyond it's background, that is, the background doesn't adapt the the increased width of the `<li>`.

Comment: @Fico: thank you but note that in the Google Chrome Console, there's no 'arrow' next to `width:462px` (see screenshot left bottom panel). I believe the absence of this arrow means that there's no CSS rule whatsoever that specifies this width because its value derives from `auto`.

Comment: how about display: block on the li's?

Comment: @hcharge: yes, that fixes the background issue! However, I do lose my list-style because of this ...

Comment: so you don't get the numbering if they're display block? li's should be block by default. can you not create a jsfiddle or jsbin? just to clarify, what are you floating left/displaying inline block?

Comment: @hcharge: I thought so too but the default display for a `<li>` is **not** `block` but `list-item`, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). It is this `display:list-item` that triggers the numbering.

Comment: UPDATE: thanks everyone for the solutions you offered but none of them are necessary. The real problem seems to be a bug in Google Chrome. On loading my page, it is not rendered correctly. But when I zoom to 90% and back to 100%, the problem is mysteriously solved. For a 15 second demo, watch [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116120595/images/chrome_bug.swf).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting white-space: nowrap onto the li elements

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your html project with this css code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Otherwise, you can override this value like this:

Css:

```
ol,li {
width: 100% !important;
}
```